# MySQL query, two tables with order group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, bills and linesbill. I need all the products that a customer has ever bought. I've gotten this to work:

```
SELECT referencia, codcliente, pvpunitario, t2.fecha FROM 
lineasfacturascli T1
INNER JOIN facturascli T2 ON T1.idfactura = T2.idfactura
WHERE T2.codcliente = "000001"
GROUP BY referencia
```

But I need get the last price that the customer has paid for each product. I'm trying to order by `"fecha"->(date)` but it does not work.

Tables structure

```
 facturascli 
   idfactura(id bill), 
   codcliente(client id), 
   fecha(date)

 lineasfacturascli 
   referencia(name of product), 
   idfactura(id bill) 
   pvpunitario(price)
```

Edit

DRapp solution works but I also need to handle the case that a customer buys it in the same day get only the lower price:

With the solution provided the result is:

```
|Referencia| |MostRecentDatePerItem| |MostRecentPricePerItem|
| pendrive | |    2017-03-02       | |          50          |
| pendrive | |    2017-03-02       | |          10          |
| samsung  | |    2017-03-02       | |          50          |
| linux car| |    2017-04-26       | |         9.99         |
```

I need:

```
|Referencia| |MostRecentDatePerItem| |MostRecentPricePerItem|
| pendrive | |    2017-03-02       | |          10          |
| samsung  | |    2017-03-02       | |          50          |
| linux car| |    2017-04-26       | |         9.99         |
```

Thanks

Comment: that qeury does not work ok... https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with an inner pre-query of all line items for a specific person with a max date per item as a group by.  So if a person ordered the 10 things multiple times over say... 50 orders, you would still have the final list of 10 things, but also the most recent date the thing was ordered.

The following is based on not exactly knowing your structures, nor sample data (please provide for future).  Also, you should always qualify your table columns in a query with the corresponding table alias reference so users know which field comes from what table.  I have to assume the "pvpunitario" column is from the line item details as the price, but basic translation appears to be "unit" not price.  You will have to adjust accordingly if I am inaccurate on my impression.

```
select
      T1.referencia,
      max( t2.fecha ) as MostRecentDatePerItem
   FROM
      lineasfacturascli T1
         INNER JOIN facturascli T2 
            ON T1.idfactura = T2.idfactura
   WHERE 
      T2.codcliente = "000001"
   GROUP BY 
      T1.referencia
```

So this will give us just the products and the maximum date ever ordered by a single client.  Now, we take this result as a basis to the original query, re-joined to the line items / order headers that specifically match the corresponding MostRecentDatePerItem.

```
select
      TT1.Referencia,
      PQ.MostRecentDatePerItem,
      TT1.pvpunitario as MostRecentPricePerItem
   from
      lineasfacturascli TT1
         JOIN
         (select
                T1.referencia,
                max( t2.fecha ) as MostRecentDatePerItem
             FROM
                lineasfacturascli T1
                   INNER JOIN facturascli T2 
                      ON T1.idfactura = T2.idfactura
             WHERE 
                T2.codcliente = "000001"
             GROUP BY 
                T1.referencia ) PQ
            on TT1.Referencia = PQ.Referencia
            JOIN facturascli TT2 
               ON TT1.idfactura = TT2.idfactura
              AND PQ.MostRecentDatePerItem = TT2.Fecha
   where
      TT2.codcliente = "000001"
```

To clarify what is going on.  The inner query (now alias "PQ" -- PreQuery), is just those qualifying items for the one client in question with the most recent date said item was purchased.

So now back to the original list of all order line items joined to this table keeps the reference product ID linked.  Now, we go again to the order header table and still apply the same client code, but ALSO joined on the same FETCHA date as the maximum date found for the transaction.  So only THEN do we want to grab the detail level price / unit information for said product.

Hopefully this helps direct your final solution.  If I am incorrect on any pieces, you should EDIT your original question and supply the additional missing details / alias references / sample data.  Then you can reply comment for follow-up support.

Answer per Comment.

To get the minimum price, you would just adjust the outer select and add a group by.  Since the item is the same, the group by will only group for the prices on that specific day.  Change the above to...

```
select
      TT1.Referencia,
      PQ.MostRecentDatePerItem,
      MIN( TT1.pvpunitario ) as LeastPricePerItemOnThisDate
   (same rest of query)
GROUP BY
      TT1.Referencia,
      PQ.MostRecentDatePerItem
```

Comment: yes, this works! but How I can control if one article it has been bought the same day? Ex: result of querry:  |pendrive -> 2017-03-02 -> 10$| and |pendrive -> 2017-03-02 -> 12$| I want see only the minimum price, because if a client bought 2 item in the same day...

Comment: @aiocver, sorry for delay.  Revised answer per comment.